# Setting JMS filter (Range filter)

Tags: jms, hornetq

**I am setting JMS filter in Producer side i.e jmsMessage.setObjectProperty("FILTER",filterId1) ...

so this is one to one relationship . i.e. key FILTER is associated with only one value i.e filterId1 ( msg is consumed by consumer which has value as filterid1 )....

but i want one to many relationship , i.e . FILTER is associted with many filterId's (filterId1 or  filterId2 or filterId3 or filterId4 or filterId5 )
Consumer having value between any of these filterId's can consume the message .....

is der any functionality in jms if no then how we can achieve it programitically.....**

Answer (score 0):

You can use Between on the filter, but I suspect you should probably use a different queue for your sets. Overusing Filters will give you a bad performance if you have many messages to be scanned.

I would favor Subscriptions with a filter, or simply use multiple queues for the stuff you need.

But that's going a big beyond simply answering your question, a simple answer would be use BETWEEN on the filter clause at your consumer.

(Also: there's no such thing as JMS Filter in Producer. a Filter only applies to a consumer. I assume you meant setting some data that will be used on the filter).

Comment: That means I should use message selectors rt?

Comment: That means I should use message selectors like this....rt? MessageConsumer tconsumer= session.createConsumer(queue,"filterId=BETWEEN 5 AND 10"); And I dont need to scan much of messages (100 messages/hr) ...so I guess filter is fine instead of multiple queue....?